# How does this integral based on the $\Phi$ function equal $x$?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, exponential-function, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

So a stats problem involving normal random variables has a solution involving a step where the following simplification occurs (based on inspection):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } y\frac{e^{-(y-x)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dy = x$$

But I don't understand how they arrived at that.

I know that:

$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$$

and:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Context:
[problem solution that involves this simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly8XV.png)

Comment: Try letting $t=y-x$.

Comment: Interpret the integral as the expected value of a distribution you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the substitution $u=(y-x)$ yields;

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u+x)e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ue^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$

By symmetry, the first integral is equal to $0$. Which leaves us with...

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}=x$$

$$\therefore\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ye^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}dy=x$$

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Making the substitution $y\rightarrow y+x$ gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\frac{e^{-(y-x)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(y+x)\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy = x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=x+0=x.
$$
(The second integral is zero by symmetry: the integrand is an odd function.)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question so fast. I wasn't aware that you can do substitutions like $y \to y+x$. Are there any rules for when you can do that?